# Devextreme Grid remote grouping Sql Query formation

Tags: devexpress, devextreme

I am evaluating this devextreme grid for its remote grouping feature. However I am unable to get enough idea on how to form my SQL Server query to support remote grouping. There aren't enough demos available that can help me getting the idea o how to prepare my SQL query to support the remote grouping feature on devextreme datagrid. Has anyone ever worked on that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the documentation section for [Remote Grouping](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/RemoteGrouping/Mvc/Light/), It works when you assign a remote data source to the grid control e.g. `OData`.

> The DataGrid widget allows your end users to shape data as needs
>   dictate. In this example, we demonstrate the use of the built-in data
>   grouping feature against a remote data source. Data is provided by an
>   OData service and grid content is grouped by both Country and City
>   columns. Note that this demo uses the DataGrid in a virtual mode and
>   loads data on-demand as the grid content is scrolled vertically.

See the reference [documentation](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/15_2/Guide/Data_Layer/Data_Source_Examples/#OData) guide for `Data Source Examples`.

**References:**
[How to implement a data service for dxDataGrid based on Web API](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T194008/how-to-implement-a-data-service-for-dxdatagrid-based-on-web-api)
[dxDataGrid - How to display data from WCF OData data service](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T139470/dxdatagrid-how-to-display-data-from-wcf-odata-data-service)

Comment: I am not using odata service as the backend. I am preparing the query myself to hit the SQL. oData won't tell me how to construct the query in case user does the grouping. I have modified the query for filtering, sorting, paging etc, however grouping doesn't seem to be having any reference help anywhere.

Comment: If you are not using a remote data source then you are hunting for a thing which is not possible in this context. Please read the documentation for the implementation of remote grouping functionality and data source examples. If you want any custom implementation help then directly contact DevExpress support.

Comment: I never said I am not using the remote data source. I just meant that I am not using an odata service, but I am using a .NET web api to do all the filtering, paging, sorting etc. I just need to know if I enable remote grouping on the grid, then it would expect me to change the query on the server with a Group By clause, which is fine, so how should my response JSON be like, that the grid would expect, after I enable grouping

Comment: Please follow the referenced link which may help you get more information if you are using WebApi..